# Fileman browser serve link for button

Tags: html, ckeditor, roxy-fileman

Is there any possibility that we can have fileman browse server link for button.So that we can have that button anywhere on webp age as filemanager without using ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

Here i find the simple solution for this :
http://yourhost/fileman/index.html?integration=ckeditor&type=image&CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en-gb"